# Recursive formula for the derivative of the product

Tags: derivatives, products

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f'(x) = f(x)g(x)$. Is there a general way to express the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$ such that
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = f(x)h(x),
$$
where $h(x)$ is a function of the derivatives of $g(x)$? For example:

\begin{align}
f''(x) = [f'(x)]' &= [f(x)g(x)]' \\
&= f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) \\
&= f(x)[\{g(x)\}^2 + g'(x)]
\end{align}
and so $h(x) = \{g(x)\}^2 + g'(x)$.

I think that using the general Leibniz rule might help, but I cannot quite get the recursion.

Comment: Note that $f(x) = Ae^{G(x)}$, where $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$ and $A$ a constant, so that effectively $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is an expression containing the $n-1$ derivatives of $g$. But the exact formula could be quite messy.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed formula or a recursive formula ? Recursive formula should be quite easy.

Comment: @Digitallis a closed formula would be ideal, but also a recursion might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is such that $f' = gf.$

We start by proving by induction that there for all $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists $h_n$ such that

$$  f^{(n)} = f h_{n}$$

> If $n = 0$ then $f = f\times 1$ so take $h_0 = 1$. Also we have $f' = fg$ so take $h_1 = g.$

> $$ f^{(n+1)} = (f^{(n)})' = (fh_{n})' = f'h_{n} + fh_{n}' = fgh_{n} + fh_{n}'$$
> therefore take $h_{n+1} := gh_n + h_n'.$

We therefore have the recursive formula

\begin{cases}
h_{n+1} = gh_n+h_n' \\
h_0 = g
\end{cases}

If you try to use this formula you will find that the derivative appearing in it is annoying so we will try to remove it.

---

By Leibnitz rule
\begin{align*}
f^{(n+1)} &= (gf)^{(n)} \\
& =  \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}}f^{(k)} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}} (fh_k) \\
&= f \times \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}}h_k
\end{align*}

It follows that we have

$$ f \times h_{n+1} = f \times \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}}h_k.$$

Hence $$h_{n+1} =  \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}}h_k$$ whenever you are not at a root of $f$. As per the comments $f= Ae^G$ where $G$ is a primitive of $g$ so $f>0$ or $f<0$ whenever $A \neq 0$ so you have the recursion formula

\begin{cases}
h_{n+1} = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} g{^{(n-k)}}h_k \\
h_0 = g
\end{cases}